# Binary files not being generated

Tags: permissions, compiling, gcc, executable, g++

When I try to compile a c, c++, or fortran code no binaries are generated and no errors are thrown  by the compilers neither. This seems to be independent of the compiler. For example, below I try to compile codes fibo.c and fibo.cpp using mpic++, g++ and gcc. The compilers seem to work but no binaries are generated

> $ ls
>
> **fibo.c  fibo.cpp**
>
> $ g++ fibo.c
>
> $ ls
>
> **fibo.c  fibo.cpp**
>
> $ gcc fibo.c
>
> $ ls
>
> **fibo.c  fibo.cpp**
>
> $ mpic++ fibo.cpp   $ ls
>
> **fibo.c  fibo.cpp**

When the code has errors, the compiler shows them. For example a missplaced d is shown

> $ gcc fibo.c
>
> fibo.c: In function ‘void fibo(int)’:
>
> fibo.c:13:20: error: ‘d’ was not declared in this scope
>
> 13 |       a_1 = a_rec; **d**

The same happens for a fortran code using pgf, ifx or any other. The executable is not being generated since when using "locate ---.out" it is not found anywhere in the machine. Any ideas on where to look to solve this problem?

Perhaps some verbosity may help

> $ g++ -v fibo.cpp

> Using built-in specs. COLLECT_GCC=g++
> COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/lto-wrapper
> OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:amdgcn-amdhsa OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
> Target: x86_64-linux-gnu Configured with: ../src/configure -v
> --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-11/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,m2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-11 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --enable-libphobos-checking=release --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --enable-cet --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-11-XeT9lY/gcc-11-11.4.0/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr,amdgcn-amdhsa=/build/gcc-11-XeT9lY/gcc-11-11.4.0/debian/tmp-gcn/usr
> --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto-lean --enable-link-serialization=2 Thread model: posix Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd gcc version 11.4.0 (Ubuntu
> 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04)  COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64' '-dumpdir' 'a-'
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/cc1plus -quiet -v -imultiarch
> x86_64-linux-gnu -D_GNU_SOURCE fibo.cpp -quiet -dumpdir a- -dumpbase
> fibo.cpp -dumpbase-ext .cpp -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -version
> -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Wformat-security -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -o /tmp/cckqbXqM.s GNU C++17 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) version
> 11.4.0 (x86_64-linux-gnu)     compiled by GNU C version 11.4.0, GMP version 6.2.1, MPFR version 4.1.0, MPC version 1.2.1, isl version
> isl-0.24-GMP
>
> GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param
> ggc-min-heapsize=131072 ignoring duplicate directory
> "/usr/include/c++/11" ignoring duplicate directory
> "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/11" ignoring nonexistent directory
> "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu" ignoring nonexistent directory
> "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/include-fixed" ignoring nonexistent
> directory
> "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
> #include "..." search starts here:
> #include <...> search starts here:  /usr/include/c++/11  .  /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/11  /usr/include/c++/11/backward
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/include  /usr/local/include
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu  /usr/include End of search list. GNU
> C++17 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) version 11.4.0 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
> compiled by GNU C version 11.4.0, GMP version 6.2.1, MPFR version
> 4.1.0, MPC version 1.2.1, isl version isl-0.24-GMP
>
> GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param
> ggc-min-heapsize=131072 Compiler executable checksum:
> d591828bb4d392ae8b7b160e5bb0b95f COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v'
> '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64' '-dumpdir' 'a-'  as
> -v --64 -o /tmp/cca5r3ME.o /tmp/cckqbXqM.s GNU assembler version 2.38 (x86_64-linux-gnu) using BFD version (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38
> COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/ LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
> COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic'
> '-march=x86-64' '-dumpdir' 'a.'
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/collect2 -plugin
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/liblto_plugin.so
> -plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccpcQmor.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu --as-needed -dynamic-linker
> /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -pie -z now -z relro
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/crtbeginS.o
> -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../.. /tmp/cca5r3ME.o -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/crtendS.o
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
> COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic'
> '-march=x86-64' '-dumpdir' 'a.'

Comment: What happens if you type `make fibo`

Comment: Hi! it shows 
cc     fibo.c   -o fibo

Comment: What happens if you specify an output filename, e.g. `gcc -o myprog fibo.c`? Do you have the `ls` command aliased to something like `ls --hide=*.out`?

Comment: No file is generated. It should create the binary with the default a.out name but it does not. I do not know how to check this aliasing ls --hide=*.out you tell me.

Comment: No alias ls = 'ls --hide=*.out' is defined in the .bashrc file.